# Windows Server 2019 Hyper-V on EC2: Hypervisor launch failed

Tags: hyper-v, amazon-ec2, windows-server

I tried to setup an EC2 `c5d.xlarge` instance with an Windows Server 2019 Hyper-V AMI (`ami-015a9a58d5a8d36a5`) but when starting the Windows Server Manager I get this error log:

> Hypervisor launch failed; Either VMX not present or not enabled in BIOS.

(please see attached screenshot for full details).

Are the any EC2 instance types which support usage of Hyper-V beside the i3.metal ones?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

According to what is reported here:

https://aws.amazon.com/it/blogs/compute/running-hyper-v-on-amazon-ec2-bare-metal-instances

Is possibile to run Hyper-V on Amazon EC2 Bare Metal Instances